# Samsung Note 3 storage looks full

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 3.

The system claims that the storage is almost full. Out of 26 GB, it show only 600MB as free.

In practice, all my pictures/videos/music/whatsapp-media sums up to about 6 GB.

Where are the other 20 GB?

Apart from resetting the phone to factory default, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Use an app like [Disk usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) which shows graphically what's occupying space. Clear what's not needed. Also see the questions in insufficient memory tag, just added to your question

Comment: I am pretty sure that WhatsApp media exceeds your estimate.

Comment: @beeshyams Diskusage only scans the sd card.

Comment: No no. It scans internal and external but for external I think it needs root

Comment: [Disk info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) is another app that gives complete info about your memory

Comment: @summerbulb Yeah, add screenshots of disk Info app in your question as beeshyams said..

Comment: @GokulNC, I don't feel comfortable loading screenshots from my phone showing my file-system. I used Disk-Info, and it shows that the `/data` directory if almost full (20 of 26 GB). Plugging the phone to my PC and summing the entire whatsapp media yields about 6 GB. What is taking the other 14 GB?